# Adding custom page template to thesis

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm trying to add a custom page template to show only one sidebar for specific pages.

I created a template page in thesis folder and I put these lines

```
<?php echo thesis_header(); ?>
<?php echo thesis_nav_menu(); ?>
    <div id="custom-page">
        <div class="content-column">
            <?php echo thesis_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebars">
            <?php echo thesis_sidebar_1(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo thesis_footer_area(); ?>
```

I found this code in a tutorial but when I open any page with this template, page doesnt show up correctly. Because all **< head>< /head>** section is missing. **thesis_header()** function doesnt bring html page's  section.

My question; how can I add all those  section just like **thesis_html_framework()** does?

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not found a reasonable method and I decided to modify structure with jQuery. This is the custom template file to show only one sidebar. I know not perfect solution, but it saved the day.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Custom - One Sidebar Template
     *
     * A custom template for use with Thesis theme for creating pages that add a left sidebar.
     *  DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. Instead, use the thesis_hook_custom_template() hook in custom/places_template_functions.php
     *
     * @package Thesis
     */
    add_action('thesis_hook_after_html', 'set_one_sidebar');

    thesis_html_framework();

    function set_one_sidebar(){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
        <!--
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sidebar_2').hide();
            $('#sidebars').css('width', '230px');
            $('#content').css('width', '718px');
            $('#content_box').css('background-position', '715px');
        });
        //-->
        </SCRIPT>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a better solution? I spent a day or two trying to find out how to rebuild the thesis framework so I could adjust the width of the site for a handfull of pages. Ended up using your fix after I tried (successfully) to override the css after calling the framework function.

something like:

```
thesis_html_framework();
<style> css stuff </style>
```

that gets tossed at the end of the body, probably not a good solution either.

Comment: may be not a good solution but it saves the day.. in some cases it's the best we can do..